# Add class to the link before a sub-menu, not the list item before it

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to do almost exactly what this function does in Wordpress:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', function ($items) {
    $hasSub = function ($menu_item_id, &$items) {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->menu_item_parent && $item->menu_item_parent==$menu_item_id) {
                return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
     };

     foreach ($items as &$item) {
         if ($hasSub($item->ID, &$items)) {
             $item->classes[] = 'menu-parent-item'; // all elements of field "classes" of a menu item get join together and render to class attribute of <li> element in HTML
         }
     }
     return $items;    
 });
```

This handy function attaches a class "menu-parent-item" to the li that contains a sub-menu. What I would like to do is add that same class (or any other usable class of course) to the link beforehand instead. In other words I would end up with this:

```
<li>
    <a href="index.php" class="menu-parent-item">Homepage</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
```

And so forth. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use jQuery

`$('ul.sub-menu').parent().addClass('menu-parent-item');`

**EDIT:** well, with your edit, you could just use the [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method?

`$('ul.sub-menu').prev().addClass('menu-parent-item');`

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for the suggestion, and I thought you had it there for a second, but the li is actually the parent. I've modified the example as such :(

Comment: Let me give that a shot and I'll report back :)

Comment: Success! Once I contained it within a function it worked fine: $(function () { $('ul.sub-menu').prev().addClass('menu-parent-item'); });